# Online LSTM classification model giving very high number of wrong predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, text-classification

I am trying to implement an online classification model using the 20 news groups data-set to classify the posts into relevant groups.

**pre-processing**: I am going through all the posts and making a dictionary with the words.Then I am indexing the words starting from 1. I then iterate through all the posts and for each word in a post I am searching the vocabulary and putting the relevant index number into an array. Then I padded all the arrays by putting 0s at the end so that they are all the same size ( 6577).

I am then creating am embedded layer (embed size=300). and each input will go through this embedded layer before being fed to the LSTM layer (LSTM input shape= (1,6577,300)).

In my model I have a LSTM layer (size = 200) and a hidden layer (size= 25). I am using the dynamic_rnn  cell in tensorflow for this and I am setting the sequence length parameter to the actual length of the post (length without padded 0s) to avoid analyzing the padded 0s. Then from the output of the LSTM layer I am feeding only the relevant output to the hidden layer.

From there onward, it is like an ordinary LSTM implementation. I have done everything I know of to improve the accuracy of the model but the number of wrong predictions is very high:

> Number of data points: 18,846 
>    Errors:  17876
>   Error Rate: 0.9485301920832007

**Note : During the back propagation I am training the embedded layer and the hidden layer.**

**Question:** I want to know what I am doing wrong here or any thoughts to improve the model. Thank you in advance.

My complete code is shown below:

```
from collections import Counter
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import matplotlib as mplt
mplt.use('agg') # Must be before importing matplotlib.pyplot or pylab!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from string import punctuation
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')



def pre_process():
    newsgroups_data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))

    words = []
    temp_post_text = []
    print(len(newsgroups_data.data))

    for post in newsgroups_data.data:

        all_text = ''.join([text for text in post if text not in punctuation])
        all_text = all_text.split('\n')
        all_text = ''.join(all_text)
        temp_text = all_text.split(" ")

        for word in temp_text:
            if word.isalpha():
                temp_text[temp_text.index(word)] = word.lower()

        # temp_text = [word for word in temp_text if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
        temp_text = list(filter(None, temp_text))
        temp_text = ' '.join([i for i in temp_text if not i.isdigit()])
        words += temp_text.split(" ")
        temp_post_text.append(temp_text)

    # temp_post_text = list(filter(None, temp_post_text))

    dictionary = Counter(words)
    # deleting spaces
    # del dictionary[""]
    sorted_split_words = sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True)
    vocab_to_int = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(sorted_split_words,1)}

    message_ints = []
    for message in temp_post_text:
        temp_message = message.split(" ")
        message_ints.append([vocab_to_int[i] for i in temp_message])


    # maximum message length = 6577

    # message_lens = Counter([len(x) for x in message_ints])AAA

    seq_length = 6577
    num_messages = len(temp_post_text)
    features = np.zeros([num_messages, seq_length], dtype=int)
    for i, row in enumerate(message_ints):
        # print(features[i, -len(row):])
        # features[i, -len(row):] = np.array(row)[:seq_length]
        features[i, :len(row)] = np.array(row)[:seq_length]
        # print(features[i])

    lb = LabelBinarizer()
    lbl = newsgroups_data.target
    labels = np.reshape(lbl, [-1])
    labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)

    sequence_lengths = [len(msg) for msg in message_ints]
    return features, labels, len(sorted_split_words)+1, sequence_lengths


def get_batches(x, y, sql, batch_size=1):
    for ii in range(0, len(y), batch_size):
        yield x[ii:ii + batch_size], y[ii:ii + batch_size], sql[ii:ii+batch_size]


def plot(noOfWrongPred, dataPoints):
    font_size = 14
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=100,figsize=(10, 6))
    mplt.rcParams.update({'font.size': font_size})
    plt.title("Distribution of wrong predictions", fontsize=font_size)
    plt.ylabel('Error rate', fontsize=font_size)
    plt.xlabel('Number of data points', fontsize=font_size)

    plt.plot(dataPoints, noOfWrongPred, label='Prediction', color='blue', linewidth=1.8)
    # plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=14)

    plt.savefig('distribution of wrong predictions.png')
    # plt.show()



def train_test():
    features, labels, n_words, sequence_length = pre_process()

    print(features.shape)
    print(labels.shape)

    # Defining Hyperparameters

    lstm_layers = 1
    batch_size = 1
    lstm_size = 200
    learning_rate = 0.01

    # --------------placeholders-------------------------------------

    # Create the graph object
    graph = tf.Graph()
    # Add nodes to the graph
    with graph.as_default():

        tf.set_random_seed(1)

        inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="inputs")
        # labels_ = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.int32)
        labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None], name="labels")
        sql_in = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name= 'sql_in')

        # output_keep_prob is the dropout added to the RNN's outputs, the dropout will have no effect on the calculation of the subsequent states.
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")

        # Size of the embedding vectors (number of units in the embedding layer)
        embed_size = 300

        # generating random values from a uniform distribution (minval included and maxval excluded)
        embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((n_words, embed_size), -1, 1),trainable=True)
        embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inputs_)

        print(embedding.shape)
        print(embed.shape)
        print(embed[0])

        # Your basic LSTM cell
        lstm =  tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)

        # Getting an initial state of all zeros
        initial_state = lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

        outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, embed, initial_state=initial_state, sequence_length=sql_in)

        out_batch_size = tf.shape(outputs)[0]
        out_max_length = tf.shape(outputs)[1]
        out_size = int(outputs.get_shape()[2])
        index = tf.range(0, out_batch_size) * out_max_length + (sql_in - 1)
        flat = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, out_size])
        relevant = tf.gather(flat, index)

        # hidden layer
        hidden = tf.layers.dense(relevant, units=25, activation=tf.nn.relu,trainable=True)

        print(hidden.shape)

        logit = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden, num_outputs=20, activation_fn=None)

        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit, labels=labels_))


        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


        saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # ----------------------------online training-----------------------------------------

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        tf.set_random_seed(1)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        iteration = 1
        state = sess.run(initial_state)
        wrongPred = 0
        noOfWrongPreds = []
        dataPoints = []

        for ii, (x, y, sql) in enumerate(get_batches(features, labels, sequence_length, batch_size), 1):

            feed = {inputs_: x,
                    labels_: y,
                    sql_in : sql,
                    keep_prob: 0.5,
                    initial_state: state}

            predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logit).eval(feed_dict=feed)

            print("----------------------------------------------------------")
            print("sez: ",sql)
            print("Iteration: {}".format(iteration))

            isequal = np.equal(np.argmax(predictions[0], 0), np.argmax(y[0], 0))

            print(np.argmax(predictions[0], 0))
            print(np.argmax(y[0], 0))

            if not (isequal):
                wrongPred += 1

            print("nummber of wrong preds: ",wrongPred)

            if iteration%50 == 0:
                noOfWrongPreds.append(wrongPred/iteration)
                dataPoints.append(iteration)

            loss, states, _ = sess.run([cost, outputs, optimizer], feed_dict=feed)

            print("Train loss: {:.3f}".format(loss))
            iteration += 1

        saver.save(sess, "checkpoints/sentiment.ckpt")
        errorRate = wrongPred / len(labels)
        print("ERRORS: ", wrongPred)
        print("ERROR RATE: ", errorRate)
        plot(noOfWrongPreds, dataPoints)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_test()
```

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider -:

1. Plot **loss vs iterations** graph. It should be downwards to know that your network is learning.You can use **tensorboard** for producing these graphs. Also produce accuracy vs iterations.
2. **Increase batch size** from 1 to mini batch of 64,128 depending on your system configuration (RAM)
3. **Use bi-directional LSTM** as you have complete sentences before training model for accuracy improvement.

**EDIT**

Your model is not learning weights correctly. 
Ran your code , model is predicting only class 0. Take a look at your predictions and prediction1. predictions is always 0.

Iteration: 1
0
10
nummber of wrong preds:  1

### Train loss: 3.116

Iteration: 2
0
3
nummber of wrong preds:  2

### Train loss: 3.163

Iteration: 3
0
17
nummber of wrong preds:  3

### Train loss: 3.212

Iteration: 4
0
3
nummber of wrong preds:  4

### Train loss: 2.992

Iteration: 5
0
4
nummber of wrong preds:  5

### Train loss: 2.892

Iteration: 6
0
12
nummber of wrong preds:  6

### Train loss: 3.077

Iteration: 7
0
4
nummber of wrong preds:  7

### Train loss: 2.546

Iteration: 8
0
10
nummber of wrong preds:  8

### Train loss: 3.459

Iteration: 9
0
10
nummber of wrong preds:  9

### Train loss: 2.341

Iteration: 10
0
19
nummber of wrong preds:  10

### Train loss: 3.303

Iteration: 11
0
19
nummber of wrong preds:  11

### Train loss: 3.193

Iteration: 12
0
11
nummber of wrong preds:  12

### Train loss: 3.323

Iteration: 13
0
19
nummber of wrong preds:  13

### Train loss: 2.773

Iteration: 14
0
13
nummber of wrong preds:  14

### Train loss: 3.129

Iteration: 15
0
0
nummber of wrong preds:  14

### Train loss: 3.992

Iteration: 16
0
17
nummber of wrong preds:  15

### Train loss: 3.010

Iteration: 17
0
12
nummber of wrong preds:  16

### Train loss: 2.534

Iteration: 18
0
12
nummber of wrong preds:  17

### Train loss: 2.804

Iteration: 19
0
11
nummber of wrong preds:  18

### Train loss: 4.369

Iteration: 20
0
8
nummber of wrong preds:  19

### Train loss: 4.028

Iteration: 21
0
7
nummber of wrong preds:  20

### Train loss: 3.844

Iteration: 22
0
5
nummber of wrong preds:  21

### Train loss: 3.579

Iteration: 23
0
1
nummber of wrong preds:  22

### Train loss: 3.418

Iteration: 24
0
8
nummber of wrong preds:  23

### Train loss: 4.337

Iteration: 25
0
10
nummber of wrong preds:  24

### Train loss: 2.328

Iteration: 26
0
14
nummber of wrong preds:  25

### Train loss: 4.216

Iteration: 27
0
16
nummber of wrong preds:  26

### Train loss: 3.155

Iteration: 28
0
1
nummber of wrong preds:  27

### Train loss: 3.307

Iteration: 29
0
6
nummber of wrong preds:  28

### Train loss: 3.744

Iteration: 30
0
0
nummber of wrong preds:  28

### Train loss: 4.180

Iteration: 31
0
7
nummber of wrong preds:  29

### Train loss: 3.400

Iteration: 32
0
16
nummber of wrong preds:  30

### Train loss: 2.706

Iteration: 33
0
5
nummber of wrong preds:  31

### Train loss: 2.994

Iteration: 34
0
9
nummber of wrong preds:  32

### Train loss: 3.610

Iteration: 35
0
13
nummber of wrong preds:  33

### Train loss: 2.689

Iteration: 36
0
4
nummber of wrong preds:  34

### Train loss: 2.755

Iteration: 37
0
4
nummber of wrong preds:  35

### Train loss: 2.778

Iteration: 38
0
18
nummber of wrong preds:  36

### Train loss: 3.361

Iteration: 39
0
8
nummber of wrong preds:  37

### Train loss: 3.640

Iteration: 40
0
8
nummber of wrong preds:  38

### Train loss: 3.276

Iteration: 41
0
19
nummber of wrong preds:  39

### Train loss: 2.796

Iteration: 42
0
1
nummber of wrong preds:  40

### Train loss: 3.189

Iteration: 43
0
12
nummber of wrong preds:  41

### Train loss: 2.901

Iteration: 44
0
7
nummber of wrong preds:  42

### Train loss: 2.913

Iteration: 45
0
10
nummber of wrong preds:  43

### Train loss: 2.875

Iteration: 46
0
5
nummber of wrong preds:  44

### Train loss: 3.005

Iteration: 47
0
2
nummber of wrong preds:  45

### Train loss: 3.246

Iteration: 48
0
6
nummber of wrong preds:  46

### Train loss: 3.071

Iteration: 49
0
11
nummber of wrong preds:  47

### Train loss: 2.971

Iteration: 50
0
2
nummber of wrong preds:  48

### Train loss: 3.192

Iteration: 51
0
12
nummber of wrong preds:  49

### Train loss: 2.894

Iteration: 52
0
7
nummber of wrong preds:  50

### Train loss: 2.980

Comment: There are no epochs in this (basically one epoch). It is an online learning instance.

Comment: I'm so sorry I have made a small mistake when copying and pasting the code. I fixed it now. It gives different predictions but the number of wrong predictions are just too high.

Comment: I also plotted the error rate vs the iterations (data points) it is shown in the edit